# How to access layouts which are not calculated or not present on the display in android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

On initial load of RecyclerView few layout or not laid because they are out of the screen , need a solution to access those views.

`findViewHolderForAdapterPosition` is returning null because those view at particular position in outside the screen.

```
RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder = recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(i);
```

holder is null here

I expect to get view/holder of the views in RecyclerView which are outside the screen

Comment: Why do you want to access view which is not drawn yet? Provide more information.

Comment: why you want to access a view which does not exists? Why not just make the changes in `dataset` so that it will reflect on view when user scroll .

Comment: The point of a `RecyclerView` is to ideally create and hold only enough views to fill the screen, recycling and *updating* them upon scrolling. Yet you can pre-create views as you see fit and return them from your `Adapter`, effectively (fully or in parts) bypassing the 'recycling'.

Comment: @KrunalDave  I have a scenario where i need to show 10 forms(these forms contain 5 edit texts each) to user which i am doing using RecyclerView . These edit texts come with pre filled data which user can change. Some time these edit text dose not have a pre filled data in this scenario when user clicks on save i should scroll to that particular form and show error ("please fill it"). in this scenario screen is have form 1 but edit text in form 6 is empty so i  need to access form 6 to show error , which returns null while accessing.

Comment: @JimmyB is it possible to make yclerView hold all the views instead of view available in the screen , please suggest how to do this if possible.

Comment: @ADM i have explained the scenario please find it above.

Comment: As I said, using a `RecyclerView` for that doesn't make any sense. Use a [`ListView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html) instead.

Comment: @Girijesh, you don't need to access view, maintain hashmap with key as position and value as your form data object, if user clicks on submit, traverse this hashmap and check if the user missed any value at any position, if yes then scroll to that position and maintain the error flag inside form data object.

Comment: @KrunalDave thanks for the reply, this approach worked for me (using the hashmap). Even we can scroll to that particular position and get the values.